# Wrap-Around for Ceasar Cipher

Tags: python

I'm trying to have my Ceasar cipher wrap around. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to go about implementing it. Here is my code as it currently is:

```
maximum_character = unciphered_text[0]
maximum_count = unciphered_text.count(unciphered_text[0])
for char in unciphered_text:
    if char is not " ":
        if unciphered_text.count(char) > maximum_count:
            maximum_character = char

print("The most frequent character used is: ", maximum_character) 

ASCII_maximum = maximum_character.lower()
ASCII_number = ord(ASCII_maximum)
print(ASCII_number)

shift_distance = ord('e')-ASCII_number
print("The shift distance is: ", shift_distance)

def caesar_cipher(unciphered_text, shift_distance):
    ciphered_text = ""
    for char in unciphered_text:
       if char.isalpha():
          cipher_process = ord(char)+shift_distance
          if cipher_process > ord('z'):
             cipher_process -= 26
           post_translation = chr(cipher_process)
           ciphered_text += post_translation 
     return ciphered_text 

answer = caesar_cipher(unciphered_text, shift_distance)
print(answer)
```

While my code can translate an input into something readable it ends up removing the spaces and proper punctuation in the process.

```
Input: Frzdugv glh pdqb wlphv ehiruh wkhlu ghdwkv; Wkh ydoldqw qhyhu wdvwh ri ghdwk exw rqfh. Ri doo wkh zrqghuv wkdw L bhw kdyh khdug, Lw vhhpv wr ph prvw vwudqjh wkdw phq vkrxog ihdu; Vhhlqj wkdw ghdwk, d qhfhvvdub hqg, Zloo frph zkhq lw zloo frph

Output: Cowardsdieman_timesbeforetheirdeathsThevaliantnevertasteofdeathbutonceOfallthewondersthatI_ethaveheardItseemstomemoststrangethatmenshouldfearSeeingthatdeathanecessar_endWillcomewhenitwillcome

Desired Output: COWARDS DIE MANY TIMES BEFORE THEIR DEATHS; THE VALIANT NEVER TASTE
OF DEATH BUT ONCE. OF ALL THE WONDERS THAT I YET HAVE HEARD, IT
SEEMS TO ME MOST STRANGE THAT MEN SHOULD FEAR; SEEING THAT DEATH, A
NECESSARY END, WILL COME WHEN IT WILL COME.
```

Comment: So you want to know how to make it skip non-alphabetic characters? Can you post some input, current output and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to transcribe them into your answer:

```
for char in unciphered_text:
    if char.isalpha():
        cipher_process = ord(char.upper()) + shift_distance
        if cipher_process > ord('Z'):
            cipher_process -= 26
        if cipher_process < ord('A'):  # Deal with underflow
            cipher_process += 26
        post_translation = chr(cipher_process)
        ciphered_text += post_translation
    else:  # skip, but include non-alphabetic characters
        ciphered_text += char
```

Additionally, you need to `.upper()` the char to convert to uppercase, and deal with the underflow of characters below `A`.

Sample output (returns added after the fact):

```
COWARDS DIE MANY TIMES BEFORE THEIR DEATHS; THE VALIANT NEVER TASTE 
OF DEATH BUT ONCE. OF ALL THE WONDERS THAT I YET HAVE HEARD, IT SEEMS 
TO ME MOST STRANGE THAT MEN SHOULD FEAR; SEEING THAT DEATH, A NECESSARY 
END, WILL COME WHEN IT WILL COME
```

Comment: Thank You. My output is significantly more readable. Where the output should print out 'y' however, it prints out a "-" instead. Here's what I mean

Comment: Cowards die man_ times before their deaths; The valiant never taste of death but once. Of all the wonders that I _et have heard, It seems to me most strange that men should fear; Seeing that death, a necessar_ end, Will come when it will come

Comment: Thank you so much it's working so much better now!